# tensorflow/serving - Input to reshape is a tensor with 100 values, but the requested shape has 10000

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving, tf.keras

When I train my tf.keras Functional API model and serve it with the tensorflow/serving docker image I'm getting a shape error when I call the API.

**How I build my model:**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, DenseFeatures, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow import feature_column, string as tf_string
import os

feature_layer_inputs = {}
feature_columns = []
for header in ['categorical_one', 'categorical_two', 'categorical_three']:
    feature_columns.append(feature_column.indicator_column(
        feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(header, hash_bucket_size=100)))
    feature_layer_inputs[header] = Input(shape=(1,), name=header, dtype=tf_string)


fc_layer = DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
fc = fc_layer(feature_layer_inputs)

''' Feature Columns to Dense and merge with attention output '''

fc = Dense(300, activation='relu')(fc)
fc = Dense(324, activation='relu')(fc)

pred = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(fc)

inputs = [v for v in feature_layer_inputs.values()]

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=pred)

model.compile(...)

model.fit(...)

saved_model_path = "C:/Temp/saved_models/{}".format(int(time.time()))
os.mkdir(saved_model_path)

model.save(saved_model_path)
```

**How my Serving Signature Definition looks like:**

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['categorical_one'] tensor_info:
dtype: DT_STRING
shape: (-1, 1)
name: serving_default_categorical_one:0
inputs['categorical_two'] tensor_info:
dtype: DT_STRING
shape: (-1, 1)
name: serving_default_categorical_two:0
inputs['categorical_three'] tensor_info:
dtype: DT_STRING
shape: (-1, 1)
name: serving_default_categorical_three:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['dense'] tensor_info:
dtype: DT_FLOAT
shape: (-1, num_classes)
name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

**How I call the Serving API:**

```
curl -d '{"instances": [ {"categorical_one": "ABC", "categorical_two": "DEF", "categorical_three": "GHI"} ] }' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/my-model-name/versions/1:predict
```

**The error message I get:**

```
{ "error": "Input to reshape is a tensor with 100 values, but the requested shape has 10000\n\t [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/model/dense_features/categorical_one_indicator/Reshape}}]]" }
```

*Please notice that I just posted the crucial parts of my code and not every line.*

Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like, tensorflow doesn't like the explicitly defined shapes in the input layers for the DenseFeatures.
I changed the following line of code and it worked.

```
feature_layer_inputs[header] = Input(shape=(), name=header, dtype=tf_string)
```

I will further check the results with a real trained model ..

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue and I found it a bit hard to debug tensorflow serving. Here is what I followed.

Notice where exactly the error occurs. In your case it says:

```
[[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/model/dense_features/categorical_one_indicator/Reshape}}]]
```

With this information you'll find exactly what kind of input does it expect and where does it lie in the hierarchy of computation graph.

For that you'll have to generate graph using Tensorboard. If your model is tensorflow based you can this [article](https://www.easy-tensorflow.com/tf-tutorials/basics/introduction-to-tensorboard) and you'll easily find similar article for Keras model.

e.g- In my case it was at `[[{{node chars/Reshape_1}}]]`. So I looked for `chars` node

[image]

and then `Reshape_1` inside the `chars` node.

[image]

Now you can see the inputs and outputs and other helpful attributes like shape. It helped me exactly understand, what was the problem.